Salesforce transaction security policy apex condition not working
I have an apex class for transaction security policy, this is piece of the code:
public boolean evaluate(LoginEvent loginEvent) {
    DateTime currentTime = Datetime.now().addSeconds(30);
    DateTime twoMinutesAgo = currentTime.addMinutes(-2);

    AggregateResult[] results = [
        SELECT SourceIp
        FROM LoginHistory
        WHERE UserId = :loginEvent.UserId
        AND LoginTime <= :currentTime
        AND LoginTime >= :twoMinutesAgo
        GROUP BY SourceIp
    ];
    
    System.debug('Query results: ' + results);
    if (!results.isEmpty() && results.size() > 1) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

Problem is when I trigger this code by logging in, ONLY for the first login within any two minute timeframe, the 'results' is returning empty. For the subsequent logins within that timeframe, the SourceIps are retrieved. Why is this happening. Please help.

Hypothesis: LoginHistory hasn't yet been written for the initial LoginEvent, It may be written after the login is either successful or fails.
